# Minecraft Windows 10 Edition False Duplicate Pack

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I import my .mcpack texture pack file, Minecraft says I have a duplicate pack, even though this is my first time trying. The texture pack is unfinished and I do have another custom texture pack in the game already so that **might** be the problem but I just don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the other custom texture pack was the problem. I deleted it and added the texture pack I wanted and it worked ;)